# Blackberry displaying list in alphabetical oreder

Tags: blackberry

The code below is for saving friends list from facebook.

```
Profile[] f=user.getFriends();
for(int i=0;i<f.length;i++){
String id=f[i].getId();
String name=f[i].getName();
vector.addElement(new FriendsRequestObject(id,name));
}
```

Now i want to display the friends list with checkboxes.

```
VerticalFieldManager vfm=new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
boolean checked = false;
for(int i=0;i<vector.size();i++){

    FriendsRequestObject co_vec = (FriendsRequestObject)vector.elementAt(i);

    String name=co_vec.getSender_name();
    String id=co_vec.getSender_id();


     box = new CheckboxField(" "+name , checked, Field.USE_ALL_WIDTH){
            public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
               graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
              super.paint(graphics);
            }
         };

         box1.addElement(box);
        // box.setMargin(6, 0, 0, 4);
         vfm.add(box);



}
vfmMiddle.add(vfm);
```

How to arrange the List in Alphabetical order ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to use a [SimpleSortingVector](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/SimpleSortingVector.html) instead of a Vector, define and set the [Comparitor](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/util/Comparator.html) you want to establish the desired order.

For an example have a look [here](http://www.hrbuckley.net/2012/01/blackberry-simple-sorting-vector.html).